# reversing a regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex, function, reverse, inverse

suppose I have this function:

```
function f($string){
    $string = preg_replace("`\[.*\]`U","",$string);
    $string = preg_replace('`&(amp;)?#?[a-z0-9]+;`i','-',$string);
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
    $string = preg_replace( "`&([a-z])(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig|quot|rsquo);`i","\\1", $string );
    $string = preg_replace( array("`[^a-z0-9]`i","`[-]+`") , "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

how can I reverse this function...ie. how should I write the function fReverse() such that we have the following:

```
$s = f("some string223---");
$reversed = fReverse($s);
echo $s;
```

and output: some string223---

Comment: Why don't you just save the first string somewhere?

Comment: the point is so that you can just dynamically reverse such strings from the url so that would defeat the purpose

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`f` is lossy. It is impossible to find an exact reverse. For example, both `"some string223---"` and `"some string223--------"` gives the same output (see http://ideone.com/DtGQZ).

---

Nevertheless, we could find a pre-image of `f`. The 5 replacements of `f` are:

1. Strip everything between `[` and `]`.
2. Replace entities like `&lt;`, `&#123;` and encoded entities like `&amp;lt;` to a hyphen `-`.
3. Escape special HTML characters (`<` → `&lt;`, `&` → `&amp;` etc.)
4. Remove accents of accented characters (`&eacute;` (=é) → `e`, etc.)
5. Turn non-alphanumerics and consecutive hyphens into a single hyphen `-`.

Out of these, it is possible that 1, 2, 4 and 5 be identity transforms. Therefore, one possible preimage is just reverse step 3:

```
function fReverse($string) {
   return html_entity_decode($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8');
}
```